# Logging the exact time that a function returns an object in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, logging

I have a function that creates and returns a dataframe in python:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
from pandas import util 

def some_function():
    
    logging.info('creating foobar')
    foobar = util.testing.makeDataFrame()
    
    return foobar
```

What is the best method for logging the precise time that `foobar` is returned?

Comment: It depends on what precision you want, and what you want to do with the time. If you want to know the creation time, you can use `time.time`, `time.time_ns` or `datetime.datetime`. If you want to know how long it took to create the DataFrame you can use `time.perf_counter` before and after the creation of it, or `timeit.timeit`.

Comment: thank you, I am interested in knowing when `return`  starts returning and finishes returning the object.  how would this look like in the given function?

Comment: If you want a timestamp I recommend using `datetime.datetime` before the `return` statement. If you need the time in the calling method, you can return a tuple of `( creation_time, df )`.

Comment: If you want to know how long the actual `return` statement is taking, I guess you could create a wrapper function and use `perf_counter` or `timeit`. However, the actual `return` statement should take essentially know time as it will be passing a reference to the object, and no real work is required for this. All the work will be done actually creating the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to just configure the logging object, like so:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s [%(thread)d] - %(message)s", 
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stderr
)

logging.info('creating foobar')
```

That way your log will automatically log the timestamp for every single log you write, and you wont need to add that in on every single log you write up.